# DIY Greenhouse Shelving

Tags: greenhouse

I have a 6'x6' greenhouse structure built of [6' "zinc plated slotted angle"](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-1-2-in-x-14-Gauge-x-72-in-Zinc-Plated-Slotted-Angle-800517/204225758?MERCH=REC-_-PIPHorizontal1_rr-_-204225749-_-204225758-_-N).
I will likely build the shelving structure into the building frame using the same angle pieces in 6'x 2' segments.

[image: 6x6 greenhouse build with slotted angles and corrugated plastic roofing panels]

Does anyone have any recommendations for shelving that won't rot, has good enough rigidity to span 6', and is permeable so to not hold water. (as with all DIY, wide availability and low price are priorities)

Comment: The wire frame shelves from old stoves make pretty sturdy shelves for plants. You may have to saw off a piece or two to get them to lie flat, but they'll hold large pots easily, and give good drainage to the floor. The toughest trick is finding them in the back of your garage, or elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You HAVE to show pictures of your greenhouse setup!  I am in the middle of building my dream greenhouse so I would love to see what you are doing!  I use the existing soil like a regular raised garden with a greenhouse above.  Putting in a rocket heater before this winter.

For shelves that won't rot the best material would be TREKS or a product similar.  Made from recycled plastic milk jugs.  TOUGH stuff.  Used for decks, handrails and edging between lawns and plant beds and gravel walkways.  One has to drill the hole before using the screws (never ever use nails for any dimensional lumber attachments).  Comes in lots of colors but if you are using in conjunction with your green house or garden or any hardscape don't use anything other than dove gray.  Trust me.

Comment: And 6' span is quite a lot to hold pots of plants, soil and water.  Is there anyway to use a middle support?  You can get any size or thickness you want of this stuff, thicker the more expense of course.  If possible move the  supports from the edge towards the middle of the span by a foot or foot and a half.  Otherwise you should have a support in the middle of that span.  If not amenable to your greenhouse structure think of adding a 'post' up through the middle of your shelves and attach.

Comment: I added a photo. The TREKS would be an interesting idea. I suppose I could cut a number of them to span the 3' width of the shelf (shelf structure is in the photo, missing the front 6' cross piece). I imagine 24 3' pieces would just about fill the space and shouldn't bend and bounce too much.

Comment: whoa, very professional!  Remember with shelving you have to think about stadium seating where each shelf  is not under the one above it...and the only wall should be your north wall.  Are you using artificial lighting?

Comment: looks so much larger than 6'X6'...I would definitely use Treks.  Otherwise, any ole lumber not pressure treated will be useless within 6 months to a year.  Make sure your floor collects and directs water drainage where you want it to go.  Are you going to heat this little house?  Do you have a great way to open it up so it doesn't cook your plants during the hot summer days?  Is this a greenhouse kit?  You'll be able to grow LOTS in this small area!  Get Shane Smith's Greenhouse growing book!!  He is so good and the book is very detailed.

Comment: I'm in coastal central CA, so, cooling will be a higher priority than heating, but I'm shooting for consistent mild temps and protection from small frosts. It's not a kit, but, after looking over the costs, a kit would have likely been more economical. I'll going to need to ponder the various venting and sealing options I have. In the mean time, I'll be sure to look up Shane's book. Thanks for the input.